# Security benefit of browsers automatically rewriting HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: tls, http, hsts

I often use a guest WiFi which does the usual intercept; attempt to navigate to any HTTP website and it redirects you to the "Agree to our ToS" page, after which it will permit any traffic from your MAC address in the normal way.

Usually I just pick any web page and hit reload, but this WiFi does not like `https://`.  The query must be `http://`.

OK, so I go into the address bar and delete the "s" from HTTPS, and hit "go".  E.G. `http://www.amazon.com/usual-Amazon-URL-here`

**And then my local browser puts the "s" back**.  It makes the query on port 443, which the guest WiFi blocks.  It has to be the local browser doing this, since it has literally no Internet.  I can vouch for this occurring on Amazon's Silk browser, Firefox on Android, and *I believe* Safari/iOS.

Is this a policy of web browser clients to force to HTTPS anytime the browser knows the site supports HTTPS?  What threat does that defend against?

Comment: That's weird. Firefox and Chrome do have a captive portal detection, which they try first.

Comment: @Braiam so does the device itself, but it's hit or miss.

Comment: As well as HSTS, the browser will cache standard HTTP to HTTPS 301 redirects. (A "guest WiFi" that does not permit HTTPS connections!? That is limiting and a little scary!)

Comment: @MrWhite The issue is that the guest WiFi needs you to go to their captive portal _first_, after which they will allow HTTPS. In order to do that, they redirect any connection to their captive portal until you log on through it, but naturally if it tries to redirect an HTTPS connection, the browser blocks it.

Comment: @forest "if it tries to redirect an HTTPS connection, the browser blocks it." - Ah, ok, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Harper If a post answered your question, please mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 33):

I suggest you look into [NeverSSL](http://neverssl.com/), a simple site which will always be served over plain HTTP.

If you are sure it is your browser doing it and not a redirect on the server side, it is likely the result of a security feature called [HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](https://scotthelme.co.uk/hsts-the-missing-link-in-tls/). When a website wants to only serve over an encrypted connection, it sets an HTTP header that instructs the browser to only ever connect over TLS. Some sites may even use [HSTS preloading](https://hstspreload.org/), where the redirection policy is hardcoded into the browsers by default, rather than being set via an HTTP header over the network. HSTS of all kinds is designed to defeat [MITM attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/124279/106285) that exploit the fact that your browser would be perfectly happy to stay on the non-encrypted version of a site, even if HTTPS is available. According to [Security Headers](https://securityheaders.com/?q=amazon.com&followRedirects=on), Amazon uses HSTS. This explains why you are being redirected.

Comment: Good to know that website exists. I've always used example.com, but no guarantees that'll work forever I guess.

Comment: @multithr3at3d `example.com` is probably one of the safer choices, actually. That said, having alternatives rarely hurts.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling But `example.com` supports HTTPS. It could start using HSTS just to make a point, or the browser may be using HTTPS Everywhere which may redirect it.

Answer (score 7):

In some browsers you can verify using debugger tools that the browser is rewriting http:// to https:// because of HSTS.  For example, in Google Chrome:

1. hit F12 to open debugger tools and go to the Network tab
2. go to http://www.amazon.com/ in the address bar
3. the Network tab will quickly fill up with a list of all the URLs being requested; scroll to the top

The first request will be for http://www.amazon.com/ .  When I select that request, in the right-hand box I see these lines (among others):

```
Request URL: http://www.amazon.com/  
Status Code: 307 Internal Redirect  
Location: https://www.amazon.com/  
Non-Authoritative-Reason: HSTS
```